# Is there a wifi to ethernet adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I would like to get a [TiVo Mini](https://www.tivo.com/shop/mini), but bafflingly it does not seem to support WiFi.  I don't have cable or ethernet in the room I wish to use it in, and it seems like it must be on the same subnet as the TiVo or I could possibly use a wireless extender.  Is there any device that will let me connect to my WiFi and provide a bridge to connect to the Mini's ethernet port so that it would be on the same subnet as my TiVo?

Comment: I use this little guy and it's works wonderfully http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833704048

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Access Points are suitable for you!
Just configure them as "Client", and connect the AP to the device with a crossover cable.

Example with linksys: [Linksys KB](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4202)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [Wireless Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_bridge).

A device such as this [Netgear](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/netgear-ieee-802-11n-300-mbps-wireless-bridge/1002457.p?id=1218207316028&skuId=1002457) connects as a client to your existing Wireless Adapter and acts as a bridge to the ethernet cabled device. There are a lot of different makes and models and some are called wireless game adapters for consoles that only had ethernet such as the earlier Xbox 360s.